# Dropdown links not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar with a dropdown menu.

```css
body{margin:0;}
#navbar {
  overflow: hidden; 
  background-color: #222d3d;
  margin-left: 25px;
}
#navwrap{
    background-color: #222d3d;
    width: 100%;
}
#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #577baf;
}

#navbar a.active {
    background-color: #577baf;
}
.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
 }

 .dropdown-content{
    margin-top: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #222d3d;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

.dropdown-content a {
     color: white
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #577baf}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #222d3d;
    display: block;
 }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
             <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
               <a href="#">Link 3</a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

This should make a working dropdown, but instead it makes this:
[image: screenshot]

I would like the links in the dropdown to be the same width as the button above them. There is probably just a basic style missing, butI have tried different positioning and it doesn't work. How can I make the links display correctly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try giving the `.dropbtn` a `display:block` instead of `inline-block`. That way, it will adjust to its parent dimensions instead of its content. I can't verify it right now because I'm on mobile.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that the basis for positioning the `.dropdown-content` is not the `.dropdown` but the `#navbar`.
By changing that and adding `left:0; right:0;` to the child, it inherits the width - only it is invisible then. Remove `overflow: hidden` from the `#navbar` and you're almost good.
The last thing is that the items in the dropdown are still to big. You need to set `box-sizing: border-box;` if you want to specify the outer width (including padding and border) of an element.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8abL3y8e/)

Changes (commented = removed):

```
#navbar {
    overflow: visible; 
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    /* margin-top: 48px; */
    top: 48px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

By the way, you could simplify your rules if you change the rule `#navbar a { float: left; }`. It will work fine without it if you change the items to `inline-block`. Now it also affects the `a` elements in the `.dropdown-content`. Without it you'd need less rules on them to counteract the float.

Answer (score 2):

Henry, I've managed to get the navbar behaving by using a list (not sure if that's acceptable). Maybe someone would be able to come with a better solution. It does make some semantic sense to use list elements to describe the menu but this is personal preference.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #222d3d;
}
li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #577baf;
}

li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #222d3d;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #577baf
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <div class="dropbtn">Dropdown</div>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```